# syntax error on token variabledeclaratorid expected after this token

Tags: java, android, mobile

Im getting "syntax error on token variabledeclaratorid expected after this token" on the following line

```
  listAq = new AQuery(this);
```

Here is my full code

```
 package com.example.test;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {



    private AQuery aq;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }

    listAq = new AQuery(this);

    ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> aa = new ArrayAdatper<JSONObject>(this, R.layout.activity_main, items){


        @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            if(convertView == null){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            }

            JSONObject jo = getItem(position);

            AQuery aq = listAq.recycle(convertView);
            aq.id(R.id.name).text(jo.optString("titleNoFormating", "No Title"));
            aq.id(R.id.meta).text(jo.optString("publisher", ""));

            String tb = jo.optJSONObject("image").optString("tbUrl");
            aq.id(R.id.tb).progress(R.id.progress).image(tb,true, true,0,0,null,AQuery.FADE_IN_NETWORK,1.0f);
            return convertView;
        }
    };



}
```

Comment: listAq = new AQuery(this); what is this statemetn?

Comment: move `listAq = new AQuery(this);` initialization inside onCreate method

Comment: *AND* make sure you have a variable declared with the name `listAq`. It looks like `private AQuery aq;` was intended to be `private AQuery listAq;`.

Comment: It will take you weeks to fix the code one line at time asking questions here.  I recommend that you complete some basic "Hello world" Java tutorials before trying to tackle Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move this inside `onCreate`

```
 AQuery listAq = new AQuery(this);
 ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> aa = new ArrayAdatper<JSONObject>(this, R.layout.activity_main, items){
 ....
```

Comment: @westnblue looks like you have nor declared the variable `listAq` Should it not be `AQuery listAq = new Aquery(this)`.Try this and inform.

Comment: @westnblue also where are the items?

Comment: yep the code i posted was copy and paste from google...wish i could get the full source from the demo app

Answer (score 1):

Few visible problems form your code

First in the below statement:

```
listAq = new AQuery(this);
```

listAq is of which type? It is not defined in your code It has to be somehting like

```
AQuery listAq;
listAq = new AQuery(this);
```

As you are trying to initialize with 'this', this stands for the current object. Current object will not be created until your constructor is called. Constructor is called after the variables initialization. So your statement is both sytantically and logically wrong. You need to move this statement in a non-static method to initialize your listAq object;

Another problematic statement:

```
ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> aa = new ArrayAdatper<JSONObject>(this, R.layout.activity_main, items){
```

You need to move this code again to a method to run. In java you need to have all executable statements in a method. Only class/instance variable declarations can be outside the method/constructors.

Comment: op has not mentioned about `items`. Probably its a list and its not initialized as well.