# Parsing text file in java - Error

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

I am trying to remove errors in the following code.

```
package in.citydoor.imports.catalog.tools;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args
     */  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String file_name="C:/aman/textfile.txt";

        try {
            CatFeedWriterToMemory obj = new CatFeedWriterToMemory(file_name);
            String[] arryLines = obj.ReadFile();
           /*
           * int i;
           * for(i=0;i<arryLines.length;i++){
           * System.out.println(arryLines[i]);
           * }
           */  
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Keep file on specified path");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package in.citydoor.imports.catalog.tools;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CatFeedBean {    
    ArrayList<ProductVo> parsedList = new ArrayList<ProductVo>();
    ArrayList<PriceVo> priceList = new ArrayList<PriceVo>();
    ArrayList<SkuVo> SkuList = new ArrayList<SkuVo>();

    **String[] columns = arryLines.split("/");**

    String productid = columns[0];
    String productname = columns[1];
    String skuid = columns[2];
    String price = columns[3];

    ProductVo productObj = new ProductVo(productid,productname);
    **parsedList.add(productObj);**
    SkuVo skuObj =  new SkuVo(skuid);
    //  SkuList.add(skuObj);
    PriceVo priceObj = new PriceVo(price);
    // priceList.add(priceObj);
}
```

---

```
package in.citydoor.imports.catalog.tools;

public class ProductVo {     
    private String product_id;
    private String product_name;

    public ProductVo(String i, String n) {
        product_id = i;
        product_name = n;  
    }

    public String getProductId() {
      return this.product_id;
    }

    public void setProductId(String product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this.product_name;
    }

    public void setProductname(String product_name){
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }
}
```

1)  For the line `String[] columns = arryLines.split("/");` in main class,

I am getting error "arryLines cannot be resolved".

2). For line `parsedList.add(productObj);`" in CatFeedBean class,

I am getting error "Syntax error on token"productObj",VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token".

Comment: You declared `arryLines` in yout `Main` class, not in the `CatFeedBean `

Comment: -1 for not showing any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

1. The arryLines is a local variable in your Main class.
2. The code is not in a method, it is in the declaration part of the
   class.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `add`-method inside of a method or constructor.

like:

```
public CatFeedBean() {
    parsedList.add(productObj);
}
```

see [stackoverflow.com/questions/17499455](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499455/syntax-error-on-token-variabledeclaratorid-expected-after-this-token)